I want to set Picture in Picture window scale to maximum size like match parent width without user's input (pinch to zoom in) in android
I have successfully implanted PIP for my video player App. here is code
     boolean allowed = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE);
        if (allowed) {
            Rational aspectRatio = new Rational(16, 9);
            pictureInPicture = new PictureInPictureParams.Builder().setAspectRatio(aspectRatio).build();
            enterPictureInPictureMode(pictureInPicture);
            isPictureMode = true;
            playerView.hideController();
            trackSelector.setParameters(trackSelector.buildUponParameters().setTrackTypeDisabled(C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT, true));
        }

I have tried this but I want to achieve below result just like the Photo I have shared
How to Make Picture in picture scale to maximum size.
